# 'Require JS' - like behavior in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, requirejs

I have a javascript module that is written to be "required". So normally I would do something like this.

`var myModule = require("myModule");`

I am struggling to understand how to do a similar thing in Rails (without rewriting the module). Or more generally, is there a Rails way to do js modules. I'm using Rails 4.

Thanks

Comment: I always thought you just use `require` for Node and `<script type="module" src="file.js"></script>` for everything else.

Comment: You can use require js in a variety of contexts, node is just one of the most popular ones.

Answer (score 0):

The `webpacker` gem allows for JavaScript modules in Rails. It supports Rails 2.2.0 at a minimum, so using it with Rails 4 should be no problem! You will also be able to use `require` with it as well.

More Info:
[Rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/webpacker), [Github](https://github.com/rails/webpacker), [Example that Uses `require`](https://medium.com/@coorasse/goodbye-sprockets-welcome-webpacker-3-0-ff877fb8fa79)